# Entrust laravel hasRole function was not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am using laravel 5 and using entrust for permissions. I have a username called admin. And i have a Role named admin. I have assigned the role to user id. But the below command not working.

```
Route::get('/secret', function()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if (Entrust::hasRole('admin'))
    {
        print_r($user);
        return 'True';
    }

    return 'Not ok';
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd have to do (if everything is setup properly):

```
Route::get('/secret', function()
{
    $user = Auth::user();
    if ($user->hasRole('admin'))
    {
        print_r($user);
        return 'True';
    }

    return 'Not ok';
});
```

More info in the [Documentation](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) under 'Checking for Roles & Permissions'
.